# DataInputStream not Receiving Data After Flushing DataOutputStream

Tags: java

So, I'm fairly new to sockets and data streams... And I am absolutely baffled by this issue I'm having.  I've searched for hours trying to find a solution, assuming that other people might have had the same issue I'm having, but I've found absolutely nothing helpful so far.

I'm writing a very simple multithreaded server/client program that is supposed to open a serverSocket, and accept connections from clients, storing them in a simple arraylist (I'll change the storage process once I actually get messages to send), and then a message handler thread parses the list, and checks if a user has written to the server.  If the user has written something, the program then displays the resulting message to the console.  My program successfully writes to the server socket through the DataOutputStream, but when I attempt to read from the corresponding DataInputStream on the server side, it says the stream is empty, and my program will continue to loop.  I've checked that the DataOutputStream receives the data through DataOutputStream.size(), and that the DataInputStream I am attempting to read data from corresponds to the correct DataOutputStream I mentioned before.

**User Code:**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class User {
    private String hashID;
    private Socket connection;
    private static int hashVal = 0;
    DataInputStream consoleInputStream;
    String consoleInput = "";

    public User(Socket conn) throws SocketException {
        hashID = hashUserKey();
        connection = conn;
        connection.setSoTimeout(1500);
        consoleInputStream = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    }

    private static String hashUserKey() { //placeholder for now
        hashVal++;
        return("Guest" + hashVal);
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return this.connection;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return this.hashID;
    }

    public boolean disconnect() {
        try {
            consoleInputStream.close();
            connection.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(hashID + " was unable to successfully disconnect");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void startConnection() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(!connection.isClosed()) {

                    try {
                        consoleInput = consoleInputStream.readLine();
                        if(consoleInput != null || consoleInput != "") {
                            writeToServer(consoleInput);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("Was not able to read console input");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("You were disconnected, have a nice day!");
                return;
            }
        }.start();

    }

    private boolean writeToServer(String toWrite) {
        try {
            String msg = hashID + ">>>: " + toWrite;
            DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outStream.writeUTF(toWrite + "\r\n");
            outStream.flush();
            consoleInput = "";
            System.out.println(msg + "\t was written to " + connection.getInetAddress() + ":" + connection.getPort());
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(hashID + " was unable to write to server");
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        User t = (User) o;
        if(t.hashID == this.hashID) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Server Code:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestServer {

        private static ServerSocket server;
        private static TestLogger logger;
        private static Thread serverHandlerThread;
        private static Thread messageHandlerThread;
        private static ArrayList<User> users;
        private static volatile boolean hasBeenStopped = false;

        public static boolean startServer(int port) {
            logger = new TestLogger();
            logger.log("Attempting to create default shutdown behavior for server");
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!hasBeenStopped) {
                            logger.warn("Server was shut down without running stopServer(), running by default");
                            stopServer();
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
            logger.log("Shutdown behaivor created. Now attempting to set up user database"/*TODO create a real database*/);
            users = new ArrayList<User>();
            logger.log("Attempting to start server");

            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(port);
                logger.log("Server successfully started at " + server.getInetAddress() + ":" + server.getLocalPort() +", now attempting to start user connection handler");
                serverHandlerThread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        this.setName("serverHandlerThread");
                        while(!server.isClosed()) {
                            try {
                                Socket temp = server.accept();
                                logger.log("Connection accepted from " + temp.getInetAddress());
                                System.out.println("Connection accepted from " + temp.getInetAddress());
                                startUserConnection(new User(temp));
                            } catch (SocketException e) {
                                logger.warn("Server was closed while in accept phase");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        logger.log(this.getName() + " was stopped, server socket was closed successfully");
                        return;
                    }
                };

                serverHandlerThread.start();
                logger.log("Server thread successfully started, listening for connections on: " + server.getInetAddress().toString() + ":" + port);

                logger.log("Attempting to start message handler thread to read user inputs");
                messageHandlerThread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        this.setName("messageHandlerThread");
                        while(!server.isClosed()) {
                            if(users.isEmpty()) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                                User temp = users.get(i);
                                try {
                                    System.out.println(new DataInputStream(temp.getSocket().getInputStream()).readUTF());
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    System.err.println("Nothing to read from client: " + temp.getID());
                                }
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                messageHandlerThread.start();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Could not bind server socket to port.");
                return false;
            }

        }

        public static boolean stopServer() {
            logger.log("Started shut down process");
            if(serverHandlerThread == null || !serverHandlerThread.isAlive()) {
                logger.warn("Thread has not been started yet or has already been killed");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                stopAllUserConnections();

                try {
                    server.close();
                    hasBeenStopped = true;
                    while(serverHandlerThread.isAlive()) {

                    }
                    logger.log("Server was successfully shut down");
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Could not close server socket");
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

        private static void startUserConnection(User user) {
            logger.log("Connected new user from " + user.getSocket().getInetAddress());
            users.add(user);
            System.out.println(user.getID() + " was added to list");
            user.startConnection();
        }

        private static boolean stopUserConnection(User user) {
            logger.log("Attempting to disconnect user, address: " + user.getSocket().getInetAddress());
            for(User u : users) {
                if(u.equals(user)) {
                    u.disconnect();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            logger.warn("Could not find user with address: " + user.getSocket().getInetAddress());
            return false;
        }

        private static boolean stopAllUserConnections() {
            logger.log("Attempting to disconnect all users from the server");
            if(users.isEmpty()) {
                logger.warn("No users available to disconnect");
                return false;
            }
            for(User u : users) {
                u.disconnect();
            }
            users.clear();
            return true;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            startServer(*the_port*);
            Client c = new Client();
            c.connect("0.0.0.0", *the_port*);
        }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client {

    public boolean connect(String serverName, int port) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Attempting to connect");
            Socket sock = new Socket(serverName, port);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            return true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not resolve " + serverName + ":" + port);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So as I said above, this works fine up until I attempt to read the data written to the server.  No matter what I do, the server's call to readUTF() on the socket always throws an IOException and checking the bytes ready to read by using DataInputStream.available() returns 0 as well.  My sample output from my most recent run is as follows:

```
Attempting to connect
Connected
Connection accepted from *the_address*
Guest1 was added to list
Nothing to read from client: Guest1
Nothing to read from client: Guest1
Nothing to read from client: Guest1
test
Guest1>>>: test  was written to *the_address:another_port*
Nothing to read from client: Guest1
Nothing to read from client: Guest1
Nothing to read from client: Guest1
```

I know my code may be terribly optimized, and I'll work on fixing that later, but right now, all I want to know is why my DataInputStream is empty after flushing the corresponding DataOutputStream, and how I can successfully send UTF data between them.

Comment: Have you tried `Socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);` on your client sockets?

Comment: I just tried that.  Unfortunately made no difference...